# One Time Binding for Interpolated Value in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to change the default **one-way** binding of an interpolated value (e.g. ${someValue}) in the view to **one-time**?

Something like the angularjs `{{::someValue}}`

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of developers still looking for a solution to this, the feature is now implemented using binding behaviour. You can use `${someValue & oneTime}` to get one time binding of the interpolated string. Alternatively you can use normal binding syntax like this `value.one-time="someValue"`

For more details, refer to [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/issues/24)

Answer (score 1):

From Rob Eisenberg via [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss):

> There will be a way to do that once we implement binding options.
>
> There are a variety of options for bindings we want to add such as : trigger, signal, mode, etc.

Comment: It's not like there's a performance overhead anyway, right? (Provided `someValue` isn't a computed property.)